# Como fazer os menus ou classes aparecem gradativamente?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Gostaria de uma ajuda, é um projeto que seria um site de pizzaria, em que quando a pessoa entrasse no site não aparecesse todos os "menus" ou "classes" de cada vez, quando entrasse apareceria somente o cardápio, assim que escolhesse quais pizzas a pessoa iria querer aparecesse a parte de entrega e assim por diante. Precisava também que calculasse o valor de cada pizza automaticamente quando fosse selecionado a quantidade e aparecesse no rodapé o subtotal. Agradeço muito a quem puder ajudar.

```js
    $('.irEntrega').click(function(){
    
     $('.entrega').show();
     $('.cardapio').hide();
    });
    
    
    
    $('.qtd').change(function () {
     var total = 0;
        var clicado = $(this);
     
     
     $('.qtd').each(function () {
     var $cada_um = $(this);
     var valor = Number($cada_um.parent().find('.valor').html());
     var qtd = $cada_um.val();
     total += valor * qtd;
    });
    
     $('.final').html(total);
    
    });
```

```css
    .etapa {
     display: none;
     }
     
    .ativa {
     display: block;
    }
    
    .pizza {
     width: 25%;
     float: left;
     padding: 1%;
    }
    
    .qtd{
     width: 30px;
     height: 30px;
    }
    
    .pizza img{
     width: 100%;
    }
    
    .painel_nav{
     clear: both;
    }
    
    header{
     background-image: url("../imgs/back.jpg");
     height: 110px;
    }
    
    footer{
     width: 100%;
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0;
     background-color: lightcoral;
     font-size: 3em;
     
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang ="pt-br">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Title</title>
     <link href="css/geral.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
     
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="conteudo">
     <div class="etapas cardapio">
      <h3>Cardapio</h3>
      
      <div class="pizza">
       <h4>nome pizza</h4>
       <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
       Quantidade: <input class="qtd" type ="number" value="0" max="5" min="0"> nome pizza</input>
      </div>
       <div class="pizza">
       <h4>nome pizza</h4>
       <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
       Quantidade: <input class="qtd" type ="number" value="0" max="5" min="0"> nome pizza</input>
      </div>
      <! -- itens -->
      <div class="painel_nav">
       <button class="irEntrega">Avançar</button>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="etapas entrega">
      <h3>Entrega</h3>
      <! -- formulario de entrega -->
           <form id="Endereco">
                  <label for="nome">Nome do Cliente:</label>
                      <input name="nome" id="nome" type="text"><br />
                  <label for="cpf">Rua:</label>
                      <input name="rua" id="rua" type="text"><br />
                  <label for="email">Complemento:</label>
                      <input name="complemento" id="complemento" type="text"><br />
                  <label for="senha">Bairro:</label>
                      <input name="bairro" id="bairro" type="text" /><br />
                  <label for="senha">CEP:</label>
                      <input name="cep" id="cep" type="number" max="10" min="0" /><br />
                      <br />
                      
    </form>
      <div class="painel_nav">
       <button class="irPagamento">Informação de Pagamento</button>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="etapas pagamento">
      <h3>Pagamento</h3>
      <p>asdasdsadsasadsadsadsasasadsasasasasadsaa</p>
      <! -- formulario de pagamento -->
     </div>
     <div class="etapas stiuacao">
      <h3>Situação</h3>
      <! -- mensagens bonitas de agradecimentos e CONTATO -->
     </div>
     <footer>
            valor: <span class="final">0,00</span>     
    
     </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/geral.js"></script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Olha cara para fazer tudo isso você ainda vai precisar de uma conexão com banco de dados, assim você conseguiria registrar cada pizza e pegar seus valores. Sobre a parte de front end eu não entendi ao certo como você quer o site, teria algum site que vocês estão se inspirando?

Comment: É um projeto da faculdade, não precisaria de banco de dados, é pq to com dificuldade de fazer essas coisas que foram pedidas. Quando a pessoa entrasse no site deveria aparecer somente a parte do "Cardapio" e conforme a pessoa escolhesse a pizza iria para a parte da entrega que seria o endereço, depois sumiria o cardapio e a entrega e iria para a parte de pagamento, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Desculpe pela demora, bem pelo que vi é so deixar os elementos que não devem aparecer com display:none e pelo que a pessoa vai clicando em seus links vai trocando os mesmos por display:block.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>quadrados</title> 
    <style>
        div{
            width:100px;
            height: 100px;
        }
        .div1{
            background: #FF0000;    
        }
        .div2{
            background: #000000;
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
</head> 
<body>
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
</body> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.div1').click(function aparece() {
        $('.div2').css('display', 'block');
    });
</script>
```

Ou também você pode optar por criar uma classe e ficar tirando ela e colocando

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>quadrados</title> 
    <style>
        div{
            width:100px;
            height: 100px;
        }
        .div1{
            background: #FF0000;    
        }
        .div2{
            background: #000000;
            display:none;
        }
        .show{
            display: block !important;
        }
    </style>
</head> 
<body>
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
</body> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.div1').click(function aparece() {
        $('.div2').toggleClass('show');
    });
</script>
```

espero ter te ajudado,
obrigado pela atenção,
Ítalo Drago.